# Test specific button by ID

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button in my HTML file that looks like this:

```
<a class="sub-menu-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" id ="subMenuBtn"
[class.full-opacity]="getNodeResult(node).highlight" [class.highlight]="text.highlight"
matTooltip="Search options..." [matTooltipShowDelay]="1000">{{ text.text }}</a>
      <button id="MyButton" mat-menu-item matTooltip="New search for '{{ 
      text.text }}''"
      (click)="newSearch(text.text)">New Search</button>
```

I want to test this specific button in the spec.ts file, hence why I have added the id tag to it.

However, the spec test returns null when searching for the button:

```
    it('should call the newSearch function if New button is clicked', () => {
        spyOn(component, 'newSearch');
        let origButton = 
            fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#subMenuBtn');
        expect(origButton).toBeTruthy(); //this works
        let button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#MyButton');
        expect(button).toBeTruthy(); //this doesn't
        button.click();
        expect(component.newSearch).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

The truthy bit fails as the button is being returned as null. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an `*ngIf` on the parent of the button preventing it from being shown? If so, make sure this condition is satisfied so the button is displayed. Also, does the directive `mat-menu-item` transform the button/remove the id? I will have to look at your full TypeScript, HTML, and Spec file but going with shots in the dark, try:

```
// You have to import `By` from '@angular/platform-browser` I believe.
let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#MyButton')).nativeElement;
console.log(button); // ===> Make sure you see some HTML being outputted
```

Also, try `console.log(fixture.nativeElement)` to see the HTML at the point in time and make sure the button is there.

Comment: You are right in that something was blocking the button from being apparent! I'll edit my question as I haven't got a solution just yet

Comment: I can click the a tag button but still can't get the button I want to test appearing

Comment: When you do `console.log(fixture.nativeElement);`, do you see the `button` tag. Most likely not but why isn't appearing, you have to determine this. Maybe you need a `fixture.detectChanges` for it to appear?